# Change of variables for probability density when function is not monotonic

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, change-of-variable

I am trying to derive the following equation from [Wikipedia on probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) which is that for functions that are not monotonic, the probability density for $y$ is:

$$f_Y(y) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n(y)} \left| \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y} g^{-1}|_k(y) \right| f_X (g^{-1}|_k(y)) .$$

My attempt is the following: first of all, I am not working with axioms but just with real analysis and some intuition about what probability should be. Let us assume that we know $f_X(x)$ and we want to find out $f_Y(y)$. Here, $x \in [x_1, x_2)$ and $y \in [y_1, y_2)$. Also, assume that the map between variables is $g: x \mapsto y$. Now, assume that $[x_1, x_2)$ can be divided into finite disjoint intervals such that their union is $[x_1, x_2)$. Call these intervals $U_k = [x_k, x_{k+1})$ for $k=1,2, \ldots, N$. Assume that in each interval $g$ restricted to $U_k$ (call it $g|_k$) is a bijection.

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Prob}_Y ([a,b]) & = \operatorname{Prob}_X(g^{-1}([a,b])) \\[8pt]
& = \operatorname{Prob}_X \left(\bigcup_k (g^{-1}([a,b]) \cap U_k)\right) \\[8pt]
& = \sum_k \operatorname{Prob}_X (g^{-1}([a,b]) \cap U_k)
\end{align}

Now, because I model probability using continuous distributions, I can translate this result by using change of variables in each segment as there function is bijection.

$$ \operatorname{Prob}_X (g^{-1}([a,b]) \cap U_k) = \int_{g^{-1}([a,b]) \cap U_k} f_X(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{g|_k (g^{-1}([a,b]) \cap U_k)} f_X(g^{-1}|_k(y)) \left| g^{-1}|_k' \right|(y) \, \mathrm{d}y$$

Now, we combine all computations to have the following result.

$$ \int \limits_a^b f_Y(y) \, \mathrm{d}y = \sum_k \int_{g|_k (g^{-1}([a,b]) \cap U_k)} f_X(g^{-1}|_k(y)) \left| g^{-1}|_k' \right|(y) \, \mathrm{d}y$$

I don't understand how to make the next step. I guess I would have to differentiate both sides with respect to $b$ and use fundamental theorem of calculus on the left hand side, but I am not sure how to differentiate (if possible) the right side.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've basically got it.
Perhaps writing it down in a more expanded manner makes it more explicit:

\begin{align}
\Bbb P(Y \in [a,b])
&=
\Bbb P\Big(X \in g^{-1}([a,b])\Big)
\\&=
\Bbb P \Big(\cup_k \big(X \in g^{-1}([a,b]) \cap U_k\big)\Big)
\\&= \sum_k \Bbb P(X \in g^{-1}([a,b]) \cap U_k)
\\&= \sum_k \Bbb P\Big(X \in g|_k^{-1}([a,b]) \Big)
\\&= \sum_k \Bbb P\Big(\underbrace{g|_k(X)}_{Y_k} \in [a,b] \Big)
\\&= \sum_k \int_{[a,b]}f_{Y_k}(y)\,dy
\\&= \sum_k \int_{[a,b]} f_X (g^{-1}|_k(y)) \left|\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y} g^{-1}|_k(y)\right| \,dy \tag{1}
\\&= \int_{[a,b]} \sum_k f_X (g^{-1}|_k(y)) \left|\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y} g^{-1}|_k(y)\right| \,dy
\end{align}

Notice that at $(1)$ we used the previous result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am a little lost -- on line 4 I think you use result that $g^{-1}([a,b]) \cap U_k = g|_k^{-1}([a,b])$ but that would mean that $g|_k(g^{-1}([a,b]) \cap U_k) = [a,b]$ which is not true if, for example, $g^{-1}([a,b]) \cap U_k = \emptyset$. Am I wrong in my reasoning? I would appreciate your thoughts on this issue.

Comment: It is not true that in general that $f(f^{-1}(S)) = S$ for any $S$ contained in the codomain of $f$. Consider for instance $f:\Bbb R \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = x^2$. It's easy to verify that $f(f^{-1}(S)) = S\cap [0,+\infty)$ for all $S\subset \Bbb R$.